# How to use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock in queryTable() of PFQueryTableViewController class

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I have a class that extends [PFQueryTableViewController](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html). In this class's [implementation of queryForTable()](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/queryForTable), I am trying to get some data to add to build the query using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. Problem is that since `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is asynchronous, how do I use the data I get from the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`and use it to build `query` below and do a `return query`.

My code and error are show below.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFUser.query()
    //let query = PFQuery(className: "Room")

    query?.whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

    //Showing OnlineUsers only
    let onlineUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "OnlineUsers")
    onlineUsersQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    onlineUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        let usersOnlineNow = results as! [PFObject]
        for user in usersOnlineNow {

            self.mLog.printToLog("Select only users who are in the OnLineUsers column")
            query?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
            //query?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "noone")

            if self.searchInProgress {
                query!.whereKey("username", containsString: self.searchString)
            }

            if self.objects!.count == 0 {
                //https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/7O9YCHNbuEo
                query!.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork //kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork
                //query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork
            }

            query!.orderByAscending("username")

            return query!

        }

    })

//        query!.orderByAscending("username")
//        
//        return query!
}
```

[image: Picture showing function and error]

Comment: There can be numerous solution. I would have create the query on the completion colsure and call the query "right there". If its too complex, then set a instance variable of PFQuery and update it in the completion closure. Add property observer to the query property and call what you need in didSet{}

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it there. If you need that information in order to populate the table then get it and then create / reload the table once you have it and you can therefore create the appropriate query.

You could hold the user at a different screen initially in order that you don't have to mess around with loading / unloading the table view or trying to provide a placeholder query.

Answer (score 0):

I would have create the query on the completion colsure and call the query "right there".

If its too complex, then set a instance variable of PFQuery and update it in the completion closure. Add property observer to the query property and call what you need in didSet{}

```
    var query = PFUser.Query()

    var finalquery:PFQuery{
    didSet{
        //call some function here
        //executeQuery(query)
    }
}
```

One more, define the query variable outside the function, it would be easy for the closure to capture the variable.

While setting the value from within the completion closure of  you current queryForTable() function parse background call.

```
onlineUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    let usersOnlineNow = results as! [PFObject]
    for user in usersOnlineNow {

        self.mLog.printToLog("Select only users who are in the OnLineUsers column")
        query?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        //query?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "noone")

        if self.searchInProgress {
            query!.whereKey("username", containsString: self.searchString)
        }

        if self.objects!.count == 0 {
            //https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/7O9YCHNbuEo
            query!.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork //kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork
            //query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork
        }

        query!.orderByAscending("username")

        self.finalquery = query

    }

})
```

Let me know if i understood wrong, i ll try to clarify. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  When the view loads, queryForTable is called, and needs ideally to return a query for the pftable without delay.  My query required several other queries to manually build the conditions.  So I chose to dispatch a background thread that would build the real query, and immediately return a pfquery which selected the correct parse class, but no rows.

That causes queryForTable to complete successfully, and the table interface to render immediately, with no warnings about slow pfqueries running on the main thread.  Then, when my background query finishes, I update the saved pfquery variable, and call reload table data.

The logic is:

- on view load, set a boolean flag for queryIsReady to false, and a pfquery value that returns the class with no rows
- in queryForTable, if queryIsReady == false, dispatch a background thread to create the real pfquery, and return the default pfquery that yields no rows.
- when the background thread completes, set the pfquery variable to the new values needed, and set queryIsReady = true
- call reload table data, which will re-invoke queryForTable

If any other actions cause queryForTable to run before the background thread completes, the boolean queryIsReady will be false, and the empty result set will be used.